# Window doesn't scroll to the first invalid field

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs

```
scrollToFirstInvalidControl(firstInvalidControl,comp=110) { // COMP SET DEFAULT 110 FOR CASE FLOW
    const rect = firstInvalidControl.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offset = rect.top - comp;
    firstInvalidControl.scrollIntoView({ 
        top: this.getTopOffset(firstInvalidControl,comp),
        behavior: 'smooth',
        left: 0,
        block: 'start' 
    });
    
    fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
      .pipe(debounceTime(100), take(1))
      .subscribe(() => firstInvalidControl.focus());
  }

  private getTopOffset(controlEl: HTMLElement,comp): number {
    const labelOffset = comp;
    return controlEl.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - labelOffset;
  }
```

I have the above code for scrolling to the first invalid field, it does scroll up but somehow it doesn't go to the exact position of the first invalid field and stops below it. I don't know what the problem is. I have tried multiple ways but they are not working. is it because of the top?